# Chaining an element using css containing text and accessing an associated field

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, protractor, chaining

I need to access the input field in the below html. The way the page is setup I need to chain using the 'Address Line 1' text and then sending text to the input field.  The input field id changes and so doesn't the layout of the fields depending on user preference.  I am struggling.  If you need some more information feel free to ask I did not want to overload with too much information.

```html
<td class="labelCol requiredInput">
  <label for="00N36000000xina"><span class="assistiveText">*</span>Address Line 1</label>
</td>
<td class="dataCol col02">
  <div class="requiredInput">
    <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
    <input id="00N36000000xina" maxlength="255" name="00N36000000xina" size="20" tabindex="4" type="text">
  </div>
</td>
```

I have accessed like this:

```
element(by.css('div.pbSubsection:nth-child(3) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > input'))
```

However depending on where the user puts the fields it can move around.  So what I was hoping was to be able to access the label\ and use that to pinpoint its input field.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what exactly the question is... do you want to access the <input> field or do you want to know how to chain css selectors?  What have you tried so far that's not working?

Comment: And also if you can provide full html code will be useful..

Comment: @Gunderson I have updated the question, does that help?

Comment: @NicolePhillips Yes that helps.  Looks like the <label> attribute `for` has the same value of the <input> `id` -- is that always the same?

Comment: @Gunderson the ids will match everytime however will change depending on the user

Comment: @Ran I tried to post the entire html however the code goes over the character limit

Comment: Do you have multiple addresses? if not maybe you can try to get the css selector using the maxlength attribute, or the size. If the application is in the first phases of development it would be a good thing if you can ask the developers for some classes/ids, it would help in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know protractor but I cobbled together some code that hopefully will work or be close and I'll give you the thought process and some info and hopefully you can use it to fix my code, if needed, and solve the problem.

Start by finding an element by XPath, `"//label[text()='Address Line 1']"`. This searches for a `LABEL` tag that contains "Address Line 1". Once you find that element, get the `label` attribute. From your HTML, this `label` is the `id` for the `INPUT` element you want. Now use the `id` to find the element and do with it what you want.

```
id = element(by.xpath("//label[text()='Address Line 1']")).getAttribute("label")
input = element(by.id(id))
input.sendkeys("some text")
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested this myself, but you could try something like this:

```
// $ is shorthand for element(by.css())
$('div.assistiveText').getAttribute('for').then(function (val) {

    // locate the <input> by the value of the attribute on <label>
    element(by.id(val)).sendKeys('abc'); // replace sendKeys with your intended function

});
```

Or if that first locator on the label isn't specific enough, swap out `$('div.assistiveText')` for `element(by.cssContainingText('Address Line 1'))`

I tried it for other attributes (I don't have a `for` attribute anywhere in my app) and it seemed to work for me.

Comment: Hmm ok, before the `element(by.id(val))` part can you put a `console.log(typeof(val));`?  If it's not a string maybe do `val.toString()`?  Not sure if that's dangerous.

Comment: it doesn't like the 'for'  I tried removing the single quotes and it didn't like that either

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("tbody > tr"));
        for (WebElement element : elementList) {
            if(element.findElement(By.cssSelector("td.labelCol > label")).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Address Line 1")) {
                element.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='text']")).sendKeys("textToInput");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thats giving me all types of errors. It wants to use var for js not list

Comment: i guess i misunderstood the question.. are you trying to automate it??

Comment: Yes using protractor that was a poor assumption people would know that by my tags, sorry about that.